# org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFORMATION: Attempting bi-dialect session with Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver, selenium-grid, geckodriver

I set up a local selenium grid to test something. The build runs normal when connecting to another grid but when using the local grid the build just stops at this point:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.XXXXXXXXXXXX
Sep 17, 2018 3:13:49 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFORMATION: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
```

No error message at all. I wasn't able to achieve anything with -X and -Dwebdriver.server.session.timeout=7200

It just hangs there and I get nothing

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFORMATION: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
```

As per the discussion [Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end thread 'webdriver dispatcher' panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 0 but the index is 0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/240) this issue was reproducible with **Selenium Client v3.0.0-beta3** released on **2016-09-01 14:57:03 -0700** with **GeckoDriver**.

Simon in a [comment](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/240#issuecomment-250234491) mentioned that:

> The root cause was a **`ClassCastException`**. We now catch that exception, log the thing that we were trying to parse and continue with other attempts to complete the handshake. The fix was available in **Selenium Client v3.0.0-beta4.**

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u181**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.20.1**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- GeckoDriver is present in the specified location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v61.0.2*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.