# Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end & Falling back to original OSS JSON using ChromeDriver and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Below is a snippet of code I'm using to initialize chrome webdriver:

```
System.out.println("Initializing Chrome");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
//options.setBinary("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",new String[]{"enable-automation"});
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
WDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
//WDriver = new ChromeDriver();
WDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("Chrome Initialization Complete");
```

But it seems to be opening two instances of chrome, this is displayed on the console:

```
Initializing Chrome
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch- 
heads/3904@{#800}) on port 12262
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious 
code.
Nov 04, 2019 3:29:38 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
(org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[1572910181.451][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Nov 04, 2019 3:29:43 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
[1572910186.002][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Nov 04, 2019 3:29:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Chrome Initialization Complete
```

Chrome Version: 78.0.3904.87

Chromedriver Version: chromedriver_78.0.3904.70

Selenium Version: 3.141.59

While the issue is not a major roadblock it is a bit annoying that it opens a 2nd instance of chrome that will eat memory while it is on standby.

Cheers.

Comment: from the logs you have included it does not look to be creating 2 chromes instances. Can you include a little more context?

Comment: Its not creating 2 chrome instances. Due to Log4j initialization not done properly so its retrying to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to take care:

This error message...

```
Nov 04, 2019 3:29:38 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

As per the discussion [Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end thread 'webdriver dispatcher' panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 0 but the index is 0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/240) this issue was observed with **Selenium Client v3.0.0-beta3** which was released on *2016-09-01 14:57:03 -0700*.

Simon in a [comment](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/240#issuecomment-250234491) mentioned that:

> The root cause was a **`ClassCastException`**. We now catch that exception, log the thing that we were trying to parse and continue with other attempts to complete the handshake. The fix was available in **Selenium Client v3.0.0-beta4.**

The most appropriate solution would have been to:

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current level of [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

> You can find a detailed discussion in [org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFORMATION: Attempting bi-dialect session with Selenium Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369904/org-openqa-selenium-remote-protocolhandshake-createsession-information-attempti/52374070#52374070)

---

The next error message...

```
Nov 04, 2019 3:29:43 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
[1572910186.002][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Nov 04, 2019 3:29:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

...also implies that the **ChromeDriver**/**Chrome Browser** combo you are using is not the recent one as the current implementation of *ChromeDriver* follows **W3C** and initial logs are as follows:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800}) on port 9626
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Nov 05, 2019 3:41:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v78.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 78.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v78.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### References

You can find some relevant discussion in:

- [Issue 1504: Unable to Open latest chrome using latest Selenium.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1504)
- [Issue 1451: Chrome 54+ session not created exception: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context'](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1451)

---

### Outro

As per this [jar-download.com](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver/3.0.1/source-code/org/openqa/selenium/remote/ProtocolHandshake.java) article the `createSession()` in **`ProtocolHandshake.java`** file of *Selenium v3.0.1* contained the following:

```
public Result createSession(HttpClient client, Command command)
    throws IOException {
    // Avoid serialising the capabilities too many times. Things like profiles are expensive.

    Capabilities desired = (Capabilities) command.getParameters().get("desiredCapabilities");
    desired = desired == null ? new DesiredCapabilities() : desired;
    Capabilities required = (Capabilities) command.getParameters().get("requiredCapabilities");
    required = required == null ? new DesiredCapabilities() : required;

    String des = new BeanToJsonConverter().convert(desired);
    String req = new BeanToJsonConverter().convert(required);

    // Assume the remote end obeys the robustness principle.
    StringBuilder parameters = new StringBuilder("{");
    amendW3CParameters(parameters, des, req);
    parameters.append(",");
    amendOssParamters(parameters, des, req);
    parameters.append("}");
    LOG.info("Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end");
    Optional result = createSession(client, parameters);

    // Assume a fragile OSS webdriver implementation
    if (!result.isPresent()) {
      parameters = new StringBuilder("{");
      amendOssParamters(parameters, des, req);
      parameters.append("}");
      LOG.info("Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.");
      result = createSession(client, parameters);
    }

    // Assume a fragile w3c implementation
    if (!result.isPresent()) {
      parameters = new StringBuilder("{");
      amendW3CParameters(parameters, des, req);
      parameters.append("}");
      LOG.info("Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection");
      result = createSession(client, parameters);
    }

    if (result.isPresent()) {
      Result toReturn = result.get();
      LOG.info(String.format("Detected dialect: %s", toReturn.dialect));
      return toReturn;
    }

    throw new SessionNotCreatedException(
      String.format(
        "Unable to create new remote session. " +
        "desired capabilities = %s, required capabilities = %s",
        desired,
        required));
}
```

Comment: Done, Thanks again :)