# Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying... error using ChromeDriver 2.43 and Chrome through Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, maven, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm honestly not even sure what to do at this point I'm not getting any error logs in the console just the logger messages that I've put into the scripts.

When I get to the line of code where I create the Dashboard Constructor it terminates the test and declares it a failure, last logged message is always "About to start looking"

I even gutted the entire constructor(commented out all code, removed the driver parameter, and just put a print statement in it) before posting this question and when I called the print method within the class the script failed at the line where the creation of the constructor happened.

I don't understand what's going on I could be missing something very obvious. I get failure but I don't necessarily see a specific error message in the console either.

Here is the test case im attempting to run:

```
package com.symphio.testCases;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.symphio.pageObjects.Dashboard;
import com.symphio.pageObjects.loginSymphio;


public class TC_Dashboard_Search_002 extends BaseClass{

    
    @Test
    public void searchForTile() throws InterruptedException {
        
        logger.info("Connected to "+ baseURL);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                
        loginSymphio login = new loginSymphio(driver);
        //logs in
        login.setUserName(userName);
        logger.info("entered username");
        login.setPassWord(passWord);
        logger.info("entered password");
        login.pressSubmit();
        logger.info("button pressed");
        
        
        //searches for tile
        Thread.sleep(3000);


        logger.info("about to start looking");
        Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard(driver);
        dashboard.mouseMover();
        logger.info("found Icon");
        dashboard.searchBarText(searchText);
        logger.info("input text");
        dashboard.tileClick();      
        logger.info("clicked");
                
    }
}
```

Here is my DashBoard pageObject

```
package com.symphio.pageObjects;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class Dashboard {
    WebDriver driver;

    public Dashboard(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);     
        
    } 
        
    @FindBy(className="search-container")
    WebElement searchImg;
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@type='search']")
    WebElement searchText;
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[contains(@class,'mat-card'), and contains(@class, 'mat-focus-indicator'), and contains(@class, 'arrangement-card')]")
    WebElement tileBox;
    
    
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

    public void mouseMover() {
    Actions mouseOverOnElement = actions.moveToElement(searchImg);
    mouseOverOnElement.perform();
    
    }
    
    public void searchBarText(String text) {
        searchText.sendKeys(text);
                
    }
    
    public void tileClick() {
        tileBox.click();
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Console error:

[image: console]

Comment: Where is failure logs? If you running test from `testng.xml` file add the [verbose](http://seleniumworks.blogspot.com/2014/01/testng-verbose-attribute-selenium-users.html) attribute to it.

Comment: seems like after I added the verbose attribute I was able to see the actual error which was a null Pointer Exception error this was a big help because now I know what to start tackling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
...[WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
...org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

...implies that implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) /[google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) combo you are using is not the recent one as the current implementation of *ChromeDriver* follows [WebDriver W3C](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) specifications and initial logs reflects:

```
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Nov 05, 2019 3:41:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

So your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.43*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.43*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v69-71**

- Possibly you are using the latest *chrome=84.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v84.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 84**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.43* and the *Chrome Browser v84.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u251](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v84.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 84.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v84.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end & Falling back to original OSS JSON using ChromeDriver and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58702552/attempting-bi-dialect-session-assuming-postels-law-holds-true-on-the-remote-en/58709346#58709346)

Comment: Thank you so much this is very helpful advice I will update you when I can but I will be sure to try these solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the Driver is not yet initialize in the DashBoard Class.

try to extend the DashBoard into BaseClass.

```
public class Dashboard extends BaseClass {
    
    public Dashboard(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);  

}
```

Comment: I initialized the driver into the BaseClass and its extended into the test case not the page Object since the test case is using the driver functions. Im simply passing the driver into the constructor to allow use of the methods within the page Object.